# Why did Bancroft choose Ryker's sleeve for Kovacs?

Tags: plot-device, altered-carbon

After Bancroft's "murder", he uses his considerable resources to get the last envoy brought out of prison to investigate the crime. The problem I'm having is why he dumped Kovacs into Ryker's sleeve? Why not just get a custom sleeve made for Kovacs, instead of using the sleeve of a dead cop with all that baggage? Was is just for dramatic effect?

Comment: Have you finished the series? It is explained in at least one of the episodes.

Comment: I have finished the series, and I didn't see anything that explained why Bancroft specifically choose to use Ryker's sleeve. Did I miss something?

Comment: I can't put together a real answer right now, but I'm pretty sure it had to do with Bancroft getting back at Ortega for failing to find his murderer.

Comment: @svenvo7 is right; Bancroft paid off Ryker's sleeve mortgage before Ortega could and resleeved Kovacs into it.

Comment: @Pleiades yes, I understand HOW, I want to know WHY? What possible motivation does Bancroft have for using Ryker's sleeve over some other sleeve?

Comment: I thought it was because he knew Ryker was her lover and that he was on ice for (something; I honestly don't remember what), and so he used that as leverage to hurt her.

Comment: Why does Bancroft give a shit about Ortega at all? Where does this antagonism that Bancroft has towards Ortega come from? She's barely an ant to him.

Comment: *Because he can*.

Comment: Why do all bullies go out of their way to pick on people they consider worthless and incompetent?  Because they define themselves by how they perceive themselves in relation to everyone else.  If they don't regularly make that comparison clear, they lose their sense of identity.  TLDR; *The bullies need the ants more than the ants need them.*

Comment: @fiend: Power corrupts and absolute power corrupts absolutely. The Meths are extremely old and powerful. One of the themes of the series is that humans are not meant to live that long as it  can drive them crazy. Bancroft has a god complex and Ortega openly showed contempt for him so he decided to teach her a lesson or two about who's really in charge. He was also pissed because she ruled his death was a failed suicide.

Comment: That title is a bit of a spoiler for people who haven't seen the show yet. Please consider editing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoiler Alert!

> In one of the episodes it is revealed that Ryker is Ortega's lover and police partner!
>  Bancroft intentionally put Tak into Ryker's body to mess with Ortega because he felt she bungled the original investigation to solve his murder. And he felt she didn't give him enough respect.
>
> Later you find out Ryker was framed for murder; So Ryker's sleeve was ripe for the taking.
>
> Bancroft was also mad at Ortega because she ruled his death a suicide. That means Bancroft is a coward and he could not let that insult slide.
>
> Rei was also angry at Ortega for failing to show her the proper amount of respect and that caused Tak to respond, "What's with you Meths and respect?"

Comment: Thanks Radhi! I messed up the spoiler tag; you beat me by nano seconds!

Comment: So what you're saying is that it was just HUGE coincidence that Bancroft's murder was DIRECTLY related to the murder of Mary-Lou, who just happened to be Ryker's friend? And the only link between them is that Bancroft is petty and trying to get under Ortega's skin?

Comment: @fiend Bancroft is extremely petty and vindictive. As other's mentioned, Bancroft paid for Ryker's sleeve before Ortega could. And It's not the only link. Rei is the common denominator here. She was manipulating Bancroft, Tak (and others) the whole time in a desperate and grandiose bid to get Tak back. Also remember, the Envoy sees what others miss, so he was able to somehow intuit the connections. IIRC the time and manner of Mary-Lou's death was suspicious.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but man, that's some sloppy and lazy writing. I wonder if the book did it better?

Comment: @fiend In the book I believe it was similar, except Mary-Lou's murder wasn't directly connected to Bancroft, she was merely one disposable girl who was fake-Catholiced up, like many others, just one Ryker happened to get involved with investigating.